# How to use external object in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

A third party sent me this script. Basically,

1. include a script
2. call the object
3. onAuthorize will feedback data, then do something with data

Is it a way to integrate it with react? I think I need the data from onAuthorize to update my react state

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>Payment Gateway Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://service.com/widget.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        iframe{border: 0;height: 50px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    * Demo for widget
</div>
<br/>
<script>
    // widget
    mywidget.Button.render({
        Client: {
            id: "1234",
            name: "testme"
        },
        payment: function (actions) {
            var amountValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inp-amount").innerText);
            return actions.createQuote(amountValue)
        },
        onAuthorize: function (data) {
            // err
            if (data.errorCode) {
                this.onError(data);
                return;
            }

            // money we need to pay
            var amountValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inp-amount").innerText);
            // we have such points, converted to money
            var pointsDollars = parseFloat(data.pointsBurned * 0.005, 10);

            // points to convert
            document.getElementById('qp').innerText = data.pointsBurned;

            // origPay - new_money = pay_now
            document.getElementById('bal').innerText = '$' + (amountValue - pointsDollars);
        },
        onError: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        onClicked: function (data) {
            // on click
            console.log(data);
        }
    }, "#container"); // container
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
<br/>
<div id="amount">
    Checkout: $<span id="inp-amount">1543</span> <br>
    Points to redeem: <span id="qp"></span> <br>

    <hr>
    Balance to pay: <span id="bal"></span> <br>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might be interested in something like: https://github.com/schiehll/react-globally

Answer (score 2):

You could create an event and listen for that event. In `onAuthorize` you can trigger the event and pass the data.

**Add an event in your page (not necessarily in React)**

```
// Create the event
var event = new CustomEvent("authroize-me", { "detail": "some event info" });
```

**React component**

```
 constructor() {
   super();
   this.handleAuthroizeMe = this.handleAuthroizeMe.bind(this);       
}
handleAuthroizeMe(data) {
   console.log(data);
}

componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('authroize-me', this.handleAuthroizeMe);
 }
 componentWillUnmount() {
   document.removeEventListener("authroize-me", this.handleAuthroizeMe);
}
```

**In  onAuthorize**

```
onAuthorize: function (data) {
   // Dispatch event
   document.dispatchEvent(event, data);
}
```

**Another quick and dirty fix.**

Expose a function from react component outside the react scope.

```
window.setAuthorizeState = (data)=> {
  this.setState({authorizeState: data});
}
```

Call `setAuthorizeState` from `onAuthorize`

Answer (score 0):

The code can be embedded in a component which renders the container. And in componentDidMount, the script can be placed.

```
class Widget extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // script here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container" />
    );
  }
}
```